# Unable to install SQlite - error with node-pre-gyp ( ubuntu 20.04 lts)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-pre-gyp

**Node version:** `14.17.5`

**Npm version:**  `7.42.0`

The problem occurs on the virtual machine when starting CI/CD (`rush update` or `yarn` command).
I think it happens when I changed my node version, while not rebuilding npm package.
I cannot change the node version because then other problems will arise.

If you are using windows, to solve this issue, you could try to run: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` and then: `npm rebuild node-gyp` --> `npm install sqlite3`. However, I'm using Ubuntu (20.04 lts) so I tried to build nodejs build tools `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential` and then `npm rebuild` and `npm rebuild node-gyp`

I also tried:

1. npm uninstall node-pre-gyp
2. npm uninstall sqlite3
3. Download the package again:
4. npm i node-pre-gyp -g
5. npm i sqlite3 -s
6. restart instance

and few more... (npm upgrade, clean chache, `npm install -g node-gyp`)

**Traceback:**

```
les/sqlite3 install: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node@14.17.6 | linux | x64
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info ok 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node@14.17.6 | linux | x64
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
.../node_modules/tiny-secp256k1 install: make: Entering directory '/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/tiny-secp256k1@1.1.6/node_modules/tiny-secp256k1/build'
.../node_modules/tiny-secp256k1 install:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/secp256k1/native/addon.o
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args [
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '/root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-f',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   'make',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/build/config.gypi',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '/root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-I',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '/root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.6/include/node/common.gypi',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.6',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.6/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   'build',
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args ]
.../node_modules/websocket install: make: Entering directory '/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/github.com/web3-js/WebSocket-Node@ef5ea2f41daf4a2113b80c9223df884b4d56c400/node_modules/websocket/build'
.../node_modules/websocket install:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info ok 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info using node@14.17.6 | linux | x64
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn make
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: make: Entering directory '/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install:   ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3310100/sqlite3.c
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: make: *** [deps/action_before_build.target.mk:13: Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3310100/sqlite3.c] Error 127
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: make: Leaving directory '/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! build error 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-1041-azure
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.6
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: gyp ERR! not ok 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/node-pre-gyp@0.11.0/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.8.0-1041-azure
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/node-pre-gyp@0.11.0/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.6
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /root/.rush/node-v14.17.6/pnpm-5.18.1/node_modules/pnpm/dist/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm/sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-linux-x64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: Failed
 ERROR  Command failed with exit code 1.

The command failed:
 /home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/pnpm-local/node_modules/.bin/pnpm install --store /home/user/slave/workspace/app/common/temp/pnpm-store --no-prefer-frozen-lockfile
ERROR: Error: The command failed with exit code 1

Giving up after 3 attempts

Deleting the "pnpm-store" folder

ERROR: The command failed with exit code 1
```

The problem is only in the virtual machine and I don't know where to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: I suppose the issue in on the virtualized ubuntu ? The issue arise in the VM that is running `Ubuntu 20.04`

Comment: Yes, exactly (virtual machine with ubuntu 20.04 on azure). I have almost the same environment locally (the same version of ubuntu, nodejs, npm, etc.) but the problem does not appear.

Comment: Do you have the long traceback ? Also I guess you do not have issue with installing `node-gyp` ? it is just the install of `sqlite3` that is failing ?

Comment: I will edit my question where I will add full traceback. Node-gyp was installed successfully. The app is building by the `rush update` command (its like `yarn build`).

Comment: I've added full traceback

Comment: Hey mate have you notice this line `.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found`.
Could it be that python is installed locally and not on the azure vm ? I am not sure why you would need python tho ... I ll dig a bit

Comment: I got it sir. As usual in the doc ahaha https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3 look for the build process ... `By default the node-gyp install will use python as part of the installation.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237356/discussion-between-paulo-and-tbone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR;

Install / Re-install `Python` and make sure it is in your `$Path`

```
sudo apt-get install python3
which python
```

### Explanation

##### 1. Investigation

While looking into the logs, to find hints on which part failed. I noticed this line:

`.../sqlite3@4.2.0/node_modules/sqlite3 install: /bin/sh: 1: python: not found`

Is it expected to be needing python to install sqlite3 via npm package by building the sources ? YES

It is mentioned in the documentation of [sqlite3 on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3), you can read the following:

> By default the node-gyp install will use python as part of the
> installation. A different python executable can be specified on the
> command line.
>
> `npm install --build-from-source --python=/usr/bin/python2`

##### 2. Fix

So in order to fix it. It seems you need to have in your `$Path` the python binary.

To check if you have it just run:

```
which python
```

In our case it should be expected to get `python not found`. I suggest you look into how to install `python` for you operating system.

For user of the `apt` dependency manager (ie: Ubuntu,...), it is as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install python3
#check if it is now present in your $Path
which python
```